# how to compile in 4.7.4 while mingw32-make compiles in 4.8.1

Tags: qt

I've downloaded QtSDK it contains both 4.7.4 and 4.8.1. And I need to compile qwt-plugin for QtDesigner in 4.7.4 version.

Mingw32-make compiles it in 4.8.1 while I'm running 4.7.4 console.
How to compile in 4.7.4? thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using creator, configure plugin to build against 4.7.4 in Projects Mode (Ctrl + 4). If you're using CLI, generate Makefiles with `qmake` from Qt 4.7.4 (it's in `QTSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/bin` somewhere; or just run `qtenv2.bat` and use that console window).

Comment: it helped it is 4.7.4 version now but still debug version: "expected «Windows mingw release full-config», but received «Windows mingw debug full-config»". qmake qwt.pro -r -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=release didn't help

Comment: Creator or CLI? If CLI, why do you pass anything to qmake when you should just `qmake qwt.pro` and `mingw32-make install` (as stated [here](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html); well, there is probably `configure` of some sort, but still)? If Creator, just configure project to use Qt 4.7.4 Release and then build.

Comment: I desided to use qwt in code without designer..